# Programatically update customer cart item quantity in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, shopping-cart

Update cart item quantity in magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initialize quoreRepository

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;

}
```

Then

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
               $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
                $cartitems->setitemId($itemid);
                $cartitems->setqty($new_qty);

                $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
               $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
                $quote->collectTotals();
```

Comment: There is a small problem for updating the cart with above code ,when i am adding the product quantity greater than the available quantity the product quantity is updated.Is there any way to validate the available quantity?

Comment: Yes , Before adding product into quote load product and extract quantity from it. But better if you can make a check on front end before sending request to api.